# Login to Piwik using PHP cURL

Tags: matomo

I would like to use curl to login and then download the Visits Overview/Summary page from Piwik:

`piwik/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=today#module=VisitsSummary&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=today`

So I first call the login page and submit the login, and password in MD5. But each time the cookie file contains this:

`#HttpOnly_domain.com FALSE / FALSE 0 PIWIK_SESSID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

So I suppose the login is unsuccessful?

I have no idea why though?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe an easier solution would be to use the [LoginHttpAuth plugin](http://plugins.piwik.org/LoginHttpAuth).

That way no need to go through the login page and play with cookies, you would just use classic HTTP Auth in the headers.

---

Update: Also have a look at [Embedding Piwik reports](http://piwik.org/docs/embed-piwik-report/), maybe it will do what you are trying to do.